# Effective login to our app via a smartphone?

Tags: mobile, ios, federated-authentication

Everyone in our corporation has a Federation ID (e.g. it ties corporate domain login to a Salesforce login) setup with Salesforce, so that we effectively have a single logon.  This works great on desktop browsers.

However, on smart phones (both iOS and Android), it's a challenge.  It prompts me for my domain login/password almost every time.  With iOS 6, the situation was livable - it seemed to cache the information, at least for the duration of the session.  With iOS7, on lower end phones (iPhone 4s and lower), Safari ends up being kicked out of memory a lot more often, and thus prompts for credentials a lot more often.

Is there a good solution to this problem?

Comment: To clarify - you're logging in to login.salesforce.com in Safari, rather than an app on the phone?

Comment: @metadaddy Basically I am hitting a specific page in my sandbox.  So https://zzz_sandbox--c.cs7.visual.force.com/apex/mypage.  That redirects me to a login URL.

Comment: One solution would be to build a hybrid remote app with the Mobile SDK. The app would be configured with your My Domain URL, users would be redirected to login in your domain (SSO), and the app would store a persistent refresh token so the user wouldn't have to login every time. See the docs: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/blob/master/doc/mobile_sdk.pdf?raw=true